# How a function in python can access the values which are declared outside its block and never passed as arguments during its call?

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

I have written a Python code in which a function without parameters can access the variable declared outside its scope. I want to know how Python interpreter can access this variable without giving any error like other programming languages(e.g. JAVA).

```
# Code 1:
def A():
    # count accessed inside function 
    print(count)
    
# count declared outside function A
count = 23
A()
```

**Output of code 1:**
23

There is a bonus question also. In Python, if we declare any variable inside the loop then how it can used outside the loop. Because, as we know that the scope of any variable will remain under the block in which it is defined.

```
# Code 2:
for i in range(1):
    # num declared inside for loop block
    num = 23
# num can be accessed outside for loop block.
print(num)
```

**Output of code 2:** 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable scope is inside-out. When you call a variable from inside a local scope like a function, first Python checks if there's a variable with that name in the local scope. If it doesn't find one, it expands the scope it checks in to the next outer scope. In your case, this is the global scope, the top-most level of scope. Declaring something absent of any context like a function or method defaults to the global scope, so that's where `count` lives.

If you want to be clear about which `count` it is you're referencing, you can add `nonlocal count` or `global count` to your function definition, making it explicit that you're referencing the a different scope.

Bonus question -- You can't reference a locally-scoped variable outside of its scope, so it doesn't work in reverse, sorry. However in your example you're using a loop, which does not have its own scope in Python (but Julia does, so if you ever make that switch heads up).